# Restoring a mongo database but mongo shell does not show it

Tags: mongodb, meteor

`mongodump` was used long time ago to create a backup, now in order to restore the database for a Meteor app, this command was used:

```
ais2> mongorestore C:\Users\AAA\Documents\meteor\apps\dump\dump\
```

```js
PS C:\Users\empl1\Documents\meteor\apps\ais2> mongorestore C:\Users\AAA\Documents\meteor\apps\dump\dump\
preparing collections to restore from
reading metadata for dbais2.dataTeckAllMatchCol from C:\Users\AAA\Documents\meteor\apps\dump\dump\dbais2\dataTeckAllMatchCol.metadata.json
reading metadata for dbais2.makeModelCol from C:\Users\AAA\Documents\meteor\apps\dump\dump\dbais2\makeModelCol.metadata.json
reading metadata for dbais2.usageCol from C:\Users\AAA\Documents\meteor\apps\dump\dump\dbais2\usageCol.metadata.json
reading metadata for dbais2.vehiclesDetailsCol from C:\Users\AAA\Documents\meteor\apps\dump\dump\dbais2\vehiclesDetailsCol.metadata.json
restoring dbais2.dataTeckAllMatchCol from C:\Users\AAA\Documents\meteor\apps\dump\dump\dbais2\dataTeckAllMatchCol.bson
restoring dbais2.makeModelCol from C:\Users\AAA\Documents\meteor\apps\dump\dump\dbais2\makeModelCol.bson
restoring dbais2.usageCol from C:\Users\AAA\Documents\meteor\apps\dump\dump\dbais2\usageCol.bson
restoring dbais2.vehiclesDetailsCol from C:\Users\AAA\Documents\meteor\apps\dump\dump\dbais2\vehiclesDetailsCol.bson
finished restoring dbais2.dataTeckAllMatchCol (11705 documents, 0 failures)
```

Since I have a directory "dbais2" with all the database files located in the above path.

In a new shell `ais2> meteor mongo` opens a mongo shell, but `show dbs` does not show the "dbais2". How can I use the newly restored database? or it was not restored correctly? if so. how to restore it correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Was the dumped DB a local one or one running in a production server?

Comment: production server and restored on the server then copied over to the local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `mongorestore` as is, it will connect to the mongo instance running on port 27017 on your local machine (if any). That's what you would use in production. Since the restore succeeded, it must be that you have such an instance running. In that case, run `mongo ais2` to connect to that instance and db.

In development, meteor runs its own mongo instance on port 3001 (assuming you used meteor on the default port 3000). When you run `meteor mongo` that is the instance your shell will connect to. If you want to restore into that, then rerun your command with the port specified:

```
mongorestore --port=3001 -d meteor C:\Users\AAA\Documents\meteor\apps\dump\dump\
```

After that you should see your data in the shell opened by `meteor mongo`. Note that in this command I'm also overriding the database name, so that the data will be imported into the database used by meteor in development (also called `meteor`).

Comment: What worked for me is mongorestore --port=3001 -d meteor C:\Users\AAA\Documents\meteor\apps\dump\dump\dbais2\